# Javascript slideshow not working on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a javascript-powered carousel from the Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 docs and i'm using it in a Wordpress theme.

I have two instances of it and the first instance, on the home page, works fine but the other fails to initialize citing a "TypeError: $ is not a function

$(document).ready(function () {" error in Firebug

Here's my code in the header:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
 <title><?php
global $page, $paged;
wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
bloginfo( 'name' );
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
?></title>

<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="wp-content/themes/xxx/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/nav.js"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 15,
scrollwheel: false,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.094297,-59.601735),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Here's the object:

```
<div class="carousel-main">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel1">
<div class="carousel-inner inner-carousel">
<div class="item active"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-53" alt="vacationing-1" src="http://yyy.com/xxx/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/vacationing-1.jpg" width="800" height="350" /></div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev"></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next"></a>

</div>
</div>
```

And here's the footer script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myCarousel, #myCarousel1').carousel('pause');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have Jquery loaded can you check it is loaded with debug tools?
please click F12 in chrome and see if Jquery is being loaded the message $ is not a function basically saying it can't find jquery

Comment: Sorted. I had to link to my js files with <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

Add a splash `/` to begin of your link like this:

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/xxx/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check is jQuery ($) available in your page.

try replacing $ with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
use class insted of id for multilple slider at single page

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.myCarousel').carousel();
});
</script>
```